# Function parseInt (1/10000000) returns 1. Why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Why `parseInt(1/10000000)` results `1`, when `parseInt(1/1000000)` result is `0`?

I need some analog to Java's int casting like `int i = -1/10000000;`, Which is `0`.

Should I use `Math.floor` for positive and `Math.ceil` for negative? Or is there another solution?

Comment: How about the raddix parameter? It produces the same result?

Comment: because 1/10000000 returns 1e-7 while 1/1000000 returns 0.000001. it differs how parseInt actually works...

Comment: @TimVermaelen same result.

Comment: That's because the result is a float not an int. parseFloat(1/10000000) ~ 1e-7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first the question seems interesting. Then I looked at what `1/10000000` is.

```
< 1/10000000
> 1e-7
```

Therefore:

```
< parseInt("1e-7"); // note `parseInt` takes a STRING argument
> 1
```

If you want to truncate to an integer, you can do this:

```
function truncateToInteger(real) {
    return real - (real % 1);
}
```

Comment: Yeah and more interestingly `parseInt(1/1000001)` is 9. :)

Comment: Bit of an "inb4" comment here, but while `return real >> 0;` would work great too, it's limited to 32-bit numbers whereas `return real - (real % 1);` supports any float.

Comment: And also interesting is that the first thing `parseInt` does, is call `toString` on the first argument ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2)), while `parseFloat`, `toFixed` and `toPrecision` does not.

Comment: Parsing 1/10000000 returns a float... not an int. parseFloat(1/10000000) works fine.

Answer (score 6):

parseInt expects to parse a string argument, so converts it to a string first.

`1/1000000` when converted to a string is `"0.000001"`, parseInt then ignores everything from "." onwards, since it is for integers only, so it reads it as `0`.

`1/10000000` is so small that converting it to a string uses scientific notation `"1e-7"`, parseInt then ignores everything from "e" onwards, since it is for integers only, so it reads it as `1`.

Basically, parseInt is just not what you should be doing.

To convert a number to an integer, OR it with 0, since any bitwise operation in JavaScript forces the number to a 32-bit int, and ORing with 0 doesn't change the value beyond that:

```
>(-1/10000000)|0
0

>1234.56|0 // truncation
1234

>(2147483647+1)|0 // integer overflow
-2147483648
```

Comment: AFAIK, x|0 is also a type hint for integers in asm.js. Just a fun fact.