# Clarification regarding parseInt() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parseint

```
parseInt(0.000004); //0 
parseInt(0.0000004);  //4
```

why does the first `parseInt()` return 0, but if I increase the number of zeros after decimal it gives 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function parseInt (1/10000000) returns 1. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650459/function-parseint-1-10000000-returns-1-why)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's partly because `parseInt()` expects a string for its argument and first converts anything else to a string.

```
console.log(0.000004.toString());
// "0.000004"

console.log(0.0000004.toString());
// "4e-7"
```

And, `parseInt()` doesn't recognize e-notation and, in the latter case, accepts just the `"4"` from the resulting string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but a new question arises now, why 0.000004.toString() is interpreted as 0.000004 not 4e-6 ?

Comment: @AkashGoel It's best to ask another question on that, (or Google it). It would not be productive to engage in a lengthy discussion about why that occurs in the comments. It would also be difficult for others to find the answer to their question if it's in the comments.